# how to pass the void function from same widget to another widget and then return the same void function from another widget to same widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I write the void function in current widget ,and then I pass that void  function to another class where I use the Inkwell property ,I use the same void function in ontap ,and how to pass the that void function to the current widget

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dose this answer your question?

```
class One{
  onTap(){
    print('One');
  }
}

class Two{
  final dynamic onTap;
  Two(this.onTap);

  doSomthing(){
    print('Two');
    onTap();
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).